# PowerShell Observable Collection Event

Tags: powershell, events, observablecollection

I am trying to register the PropertyChanged event for an Observable Collection in PowerShell, but no dice. This works just fine for the CollectionChanged event.

This works:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $MyObservableCollection -EventName CollectionChanged -Action {Write-Host "Collection changed!"}`
```

Whereas this does not work:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $MyObservableCollection -EventName PropertyChanged -Action {Write-Host "Property changed!"}`
```

The error I receive is as follows:

> Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for the specified event. An
> event with the name 'PropertyChanged' does not exist.

Comment: Please can you post how you are creating the $MyObservableCollection, and also the error your getting.

Comment: Sure:

$MyObservableCollection = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $MyObservableCollection -EventName PropertyChanged -Action {Write-Host "Hello"}                

Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for the specified event. An event with the name 'PropertyChanged' does not exist.

Comment: The ```PropertyChanged``` event on an ```ObservableCollection<T>``` is ```protected``` which means it can only be accessed by that class and any classes that inherit from it - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.propertychanged?view=net-7.0#system-collections-objectmodel-observablecollection-1-propertychanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a class that support the Property changed, so you could do something like this:

```
$PersonClass = @'
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private string _Age;
    public string Age
    {
        get { return _Age; }
        set
        {
            _Age = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Age"));
        }
    }

    private string _Country;
    public string Country
    {
        get { return _Country; }
        set
        {
            _Country = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Country"));
        }
    }
}
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $PersonClass -Language 'CSharp'
$NewPerson = [Person]::New()
$MyObservableCollection = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Person]

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $NewPerson -EventName PropertyChanged -Action {Write-Host  "PropertyChanged on item"}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $MyObservableCollection -EventName CollectionChanged -Action {Write-Host "Item added or removed"}

$MyObservableCollection.Add($NewPerson)
$NewPerson.Name = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

Here we are creating a Person class which stores the properties of a person like Name, Age and country, each with a PopertyChangedEventHandler. Once you have that its then creating an observable arraylist so you can add/remove individual Persons from the list (which will trigger the CollectionChanged event).

Comment: Thank you, KG-DROID. Just out of interest, is PowerShell not capable of creating the required class as you have in C#?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, PowerShell classes don't do events like this, even if they did though, PowerShell is based on C# anyway, so in the backend code it would most likely work in the same way anyway.